# How do I use a package language file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a Laravel 4 package language file, but I don't know how to do it.

I created a package with `php artisan workbench vendor/package --resources`. I then create file `workbench/vendor/package/src/lang/en/routes.php`.

In that routes file a I have this:

```
<?php
return [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
```

Now how do I access that? I tried with `Lang::get('routes.foo')` and `Lang::get('vendor/package::routes.foo')` but both fails and just gives me the parameter itself I entered. I'm calling it in my service providers `boot` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same like you call view and config:

```
// for lang
Lang::get('package::routes.foo')
// or with shortcut func
trans('package::routes.foo')

// for view
View::make('package::view.name');

// for config
Config::get('package::group.option');
```

What you need to do is to remove `vendor/` but leave `package`.

You can see more at the Laravel documentation on: [package conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-conventions).

====

## UPDATE

in **laravel 5** you can call view and config like this :

```
// for view (shorthand)
view('path_to_view', array('data' => 'somedata'));

// for config
config('config.name', 'default');
```

Comment: To anyone who would stumble upon this issue in the future: remember to put your translations into a locale folder.

E.g., not `YourPackage/resources/lang/messages.php`, but `YourPackage/resources/lang/en/messages.php`. 

Sounds obvious, but it is easy to mess up when you only use one language all the time in your software.