# Language files on external directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My application has theme files. My problem is how to load language files from external directory and can be loaded by Laravel base Class / helper for active local translation?

Comment: I think this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831715/how-do-i-use-a-package-language-file

Comment: and this link : http://laravel.io/forum/03-01-2014-language-files-on-external-directory

Comment: but i dont know is correct or not. any help appreciated.

Comment: If you gave the directory structure you're trying to use and some samples of your files, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: links were correct. thanks.